# What are command line arguements and what are they use for?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I came across this "command line arguments" thing while reading a coding book. Can someone please explain what is it, what is it for and when do I need it?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Fred, Did you search `command line arguements` on Google or any other search engines, you can find better article explaining the same.

Comment: In that case you should as about the parts of the explanation you didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Python supports the creation of programs that can be run on the
>   command line, completely with command-line arguments.

Example:

```
import sys
for x in sys.argv:
     print("Argument: ", x)
```

Running:

```
python demo.py Hey Bye
```

Output:

```
Argument:  demo.py
Argument:  Hey
Argument:  Bye
```

Comment: can I have an infinite amount of arguments?

Comment: How do you plan to pass infinite amount of arguments?

Comment: It is completely fine. Infinities in programming are not practical because machines are bounded by the limitations of space. If by infinite you mean a very large **finite** amount, yes you can do that but again, it will be largely dependent on the machine you are running. Upvote and accept if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

you can always start a python code from the console, like so:

```
python myCode.py
```

Now sometimes you want to tell you programs some further infos, then you would type something like:

```
python myCode.py name=George
```

In your code you can read those data and use them.

It's a very easy way to change a programs behaviour for users, admins and so one without changing the code.

Comment: So a command line argument essentially allows me to provide inputs to my program from outside of the program? and also in what occasion do i need to provide further inputs? Cheers :)

Comment: The use case is completely dependent on you, example : You need to pass a filename to be read to your code in command line then you can do $python script.py filename

Comment: Just imagine a fancy user interface, but nobody got time for that. so instead of using a file selector in a beautiful window, you can just pass the file path to the program. It's often used as automatic cron jobs, so other programs call your program and that's an easy way to pass data to that program.

Comment: @YashKrishan can you explain what "$python script.py" does? What is the "$" symbol for? I usually type in "python" and follow by the PATH "C:\this\is\the\Path to my script.py"

Comment: I just added $ to signify that we are using terminal as you must have seen that the prompt in the terminal where you write the command ends with a $ sign

Comment: @YashKrishan terminal as in Apple's terminal and window's cmd? Thanks you are very helpful!

Comment: By terminal here, I mean Linux and Unix(Mac) terminal. Windows terminal prompts ends with a '>'